# Combine month and year from jsonb data PostgreSQL 11.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have PostgreSQL 11.5 with something similar to this jsonb data:

```
[{"name":"$.publishedMonth", "value":"04"},{"name":"$.publishedYear","value":"1972"}]
[{"name":"$.publishedMonth", "value":"07"},{"name":"$.publishedYear","value":"2020"}]
```

My desired result is:

| id | publishedMonthYear |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 04-1972 |
| 2 | 07-2020 |

```sql
SELECT b.field_value AS publishedMonthYear, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(result) ::jsonb) - >> 'name' field_name,
                       (jsonb_array_elements(result) ::jsonb) - >> 'value' field_value,
                  FROM books
                 WHERE bookstore_id = '3') a
         WHERE a.field_name in ('$.publishedMonth', '$.publishedYear')) b
 GROUP BY b.field_value
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query including an aggregation by `id` column of the table `books` cross joined to `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` without a subquery will suffice such as

```sql
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(j ->> 'value', '-' ORDER BY j ->> 'name') AS "publishedMonthYear"
  FROM books,
       JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(result) AS arr(j)
 WHERE bookstore_id = 3
   AND j ->> 'name' IN ('$.publishedMonth','$.publishedYear')
 GROUP BY id
```

considering the sorting by `j ->> 'name'` which will extract the values (`$.publishedMonth` and `$.publishedYear`) as desired alphabetically.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5f0d5dc3666685807ad3c36407d83c6e)</kbd>

If concatenated "publishedMonthYear" values needed to be counted, then consider using a subquery( as expressed within the comment )

```sql
SELECT "publishedMonthYear", COUNT(*)
  FROM
  ( SELECT STRING_AGG(j ->> 'value', '-' ORDER BY j ->> 'name') AS "publishedMonthYear"
      FROM books,
           JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(result) AS arr(j)
     WHERE bookstore_id = 3
       AND j ->> 'name' IN ('$.publishedMonth','$.publishedYear')
     GROUP BY id ) AS b
 GROUP BY "publishedMonthYear"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a977cc01581f35e9df1578b35bf64b72)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your solution, I just want to extract values only for $.publishedMonth and $.publishedYear, since I have also other data in my jsonb.

Comment: ,I just want j to be $.publishedMonth and $.publishedYear. Because the solution is giving me also the email address and notes, which I don't want. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK @Ina , then need to restrict the results by adding `AND j ->> 'name' IN ('$.publishedMonth','$.publishedYear')` to the WHERE condition. The question is edited. You can check out the new demo in it.

Comment: Is there any way to count the values as I have tried to do in my initial query? Many thanks for helping me

Comment: @Ina I suppose you want to distinctly count each value within each JSON, then just add `,COUNT(DISTINCT j ->> 'value')`, next to the column starting with `STRING_AGG`

Comment: I want to count how many times "04-1972" is in my bookstore. Thanks

Comment: Then you can convert the current query to a subquery like in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a977cc01581f35e9df1578b35bf64b72) @Ina

Comment: i can't thank you enough :D

Answer (score 1):

Sample table and data structure: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3d574800212ddd69cb45950dc98a5939)

```sql
select id, string_agg(value - >> 'value', '-' order by value - >> 'name')
  from book b
 cross join jsonb_array_elements(b.result ::jsonb) e
 group by id
having array_agg(value - >> 'name'
 order by value - >> 'name') = '{$.publishedMonth,$.publishedYear}'
```